# how to update a value in an array in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to update a value in an array

```
{
_id: "5d0b939f1f0cc14f83153c43"
categoryName: "Email"
client: "5cff60a4b8b1490049e8325b"
notes: ["note to be updated"]
}

const updateNoteInNoteCategory = async (Id, newNote, index) => {
  const updatedNote = await Note.findByIdAndUpdate(
   { _id: Id },
   { $set: { notes[index]: newNote } },
   { new: true }
  );
}
```

I'm passing the index of field to be updated, but I can't seem to get it to work.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should try passing the index by the dot notation like:

```
{$set: {notes.index : newNote}}
```

And please take a look [to this.](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate)

Answer (score 0):

If I got it, I think while you using `{ notes[0]: newNote }`, you may get `{ 'note to be updated': newNote }`. (I'v tried, it's invalid)

Maybe you should try `{ 'notes.0': newNote }`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, The index is not always gonna be 0, and 'note.index' give this error Cannot create field 'index' in element

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$` to get the correct element index inside `notes`, and pass some parameter to find the element you want to update in the `find`, here's an exemple

```
Notes.updateOne({
    _id: Id,
    'notes': 'note to be updated'
}, {
    $set: {
        'notes.$': 'note updated'
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try passing the dot notation for array.

> db.arraycheck.update({},{$set: { "notes.0":"checking after updation" }})
>   WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
>
> db.arraycheck.find()
>   { "_id" : "5d0b939f1f0cc14f83153c43", "categoryName" : "Email", "client" : "5cff60a4b8b1490049e8325b", "notes" : [ "checking after updation" ] }